# What is Procfile? and Web and Worker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, procfile

Is it necessary to give 'worker' information in Procfile? If yes then what it is actually? I have already added `web: node server/server.js` detail in the `Procfile`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

> Procfile is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your application’s dynos on the Heroku platform.

From [Process Types and the Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile), which is a good introduction, but basically you use the Procfile to tell Heroku how to run various pieces of your app. The part to the left of the colon on each line is the process type; the part on the right is the command to run to start that process.

Process types can be anything, although `web` is special, as Heroku will route HTTP requests to processes started with the `web` name. Other processes, such as background workers, can be named anything, and you can use the Heroku toolbelt to start or stop those processes by referring to its name.

So, in short, `worker` is not necessary, unless you want to run some other process in the background by [controlling process with the `heroku ps` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type).

Comment: http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html This too, is a nice introduction to the subject.

Comment: @Kashyap Good call. It's worth noting that the Heroku Toolbelt will install Foreman locally so you can use the same Procfile to run your own apps in development.

Comment: Hey guys, actually I am getting one error and I posted it here - It would be great if you can have a look into this. I scratched my head to solve this but failed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129625/getting-error-while-running-command-heroku-psscale-worker-1-error

Comment: `Procfile`s are to configure `foreman`, right? So technically you could run `foreman` anywhere, not just on Heroku?

Comment: Thanks for for `Other processes, such as background workers, can be named anything` - facts like these are important but often overlooked

Answer (score 11):

You would only need a 'worker' entry in your `Procfile` if you plan on using some sort of background job system (i.e. queuing long running tasks for later). Heroku has more information here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: Also, the name "worker" is arbitrary.  You can name them whatever you want in your procfile; "worker", "emailer", "sidekiq", "ladygaga_twitter_feed_watcher". This allows you to manage each type independently ($ heroku ps:scale emailer=2). In fact, if there are multiple "worker" types in a procfile, only the one listed last will be used.

Comment: @Patrick For sure. I believe Heroku sets up some defaults to worker (for Rails apps it might run `rake jobs:work`) but other than that the name is for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was following Udemy course regarding nestjs and aws Elastic Beanstalk to deploy however it keeps failing to deploy until I created Procfile with following:

web: npm install && npm run-script build && npm run-script start:prod

Comment: You should use `release:` for the first two commands since if they fail, it will not deploy the new build. `web` is special as Heroku will route things like HTTP requests to `web` processes, so that's certainly overkill for the first two.