# Running Rake Task with Clock Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, clockwork

In my Heroku application, I have a clock process which needs to periodically execute a rake task.I am using the clockwork gem.Here is the code in lib/clock.rb :

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'

include Clockwork

every(1.day, 'API Data Fetching', :at => '18:31') { `rake build_index` }
```

Here is the Heroku log snippet:

```
2013-07-15T18:31:00.716092+00:00 app[clock.1]: I, [2013-07-15T18:31:00.673880 #2]  INFO -- : Triggering 'API Data Fetching'
2013-07-15T18:31:39.131681+00:00 app[clock.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
2013-07-15T18:31:39.132841+00:00 app[clock.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
2013-07-15T18:31:39.132346+00:00 app[clock.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
```

The task is not being executed and no API data is being fetched. What could be the issue? Is running a rake task from clock.rb bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Answer after long time :) but you need to add Procfile to work clockworker gem with heroku [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128395/what-is-procfile-and-web-and-worker) may help you.